# How to add custom header to DLQ topic record?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

The application reads records from one topic A, does a minor transformation and puts into topic B. If validation is failed during deserialising the incoming record data to type A, then the message is sent to DLQ.

```
@Bean
public Function<KStream<String, RawEvent>, KStream<String, FormattedEvent>> process() {
        
   return input -> input.map((key, event) -> {
       return new KeyValue<>(event.getAttribute().get("id"), new FormattedEvent(event));
   });
}
```

Below is properly set in application.yml

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.deserialization-exception-handler: sendToDlq
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.process-in-0.consumer.dlqName: ${DLQ_TOPIC}
```

I must be able to add some custom headers for the DLQ topic records that appear after failure in deserialising the incoming message to type `RawEvent`

Comment: I would like to add some custom additional record header e.g. 'http-status', 'reason-code' anything to the message sent to DLQ.